# No data printed in terminal

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.earningswhispers.com")

element_calendar = driver.find_element_by_id("calendar")
element_calendar.click()

data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('cor amc showconf nwh')

for d in data:
    title = d.find_element_by_xpath('./html/body/form/div[3]/section/ul/li[26]/div[1]/div[3]').text
    estimate1 = d.find_element_by_xpath('./html/body/form/div[3]/section/ul/li[26]/div[1]/div[6]').text
    estimate2 = d.find_element_by_xpath('./html/body/form/div[3]/section/ul/li[26]/div[1]/div[7]').text
    print(title, estimate1, estimate2)


assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.quit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all of your locators were incorrect.  Try the following:

```
data = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.cor.amc.showconf.nwh')


for d in data:
    title = d.find_element_by_xpath('./div/div[3]').text
    estimate1 = d.find_element_by_xpath('./div/div[6]').text
    estimate2 = d.find_element_by_xpath('./div/div[7]').text
    print(title, estimate1, estimate2)
```

Prints:

```
CRM $0.88 $5.89 B
ULTA $1.92 $1.62 B
BOX $0.17 $200.48 M
GPS ($0.02) $3.40 B
OLLI $0.66 $420.52 M
DELL $1.62 $23.36 B
GES ($0.20) $497.31 M
DOMO ($0.43) $57.49 M
FANH Rev: $0.25
LGF.A ($0.17) -
```

Just an FYI, finding elements by `class name` when there are spaces in the name generally doesn't work.  It's better to use `css selector` in that case.

Also when you are looping through a set of elements you don't go all the way back to the root HTML element in every loop, your root begins at the element you are looping over.

Comment: You are right! I just don't understand why no exception thrown for `element_calendar = driver.find_element_by_id("calendar")
element_calendar.click()` without wait / delay before it?

Comment: Yea, not sure on that.  If it would have thrown exception I would have added some waits in the code as well.  It's probably good practice for the OP to do that anyway

Comment: Sure, but again I don't understand how can it run without throwing an error there unless he always running it in a debug mode :)

Comment: Thanks everyone, still fairly new with using selenium and working with html!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it looks like data comes back as an empty array for me.

After some modification, I came up with...

```
data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="ticker"]')

for d in data:
    title = d.get_attribute('innerText')
    estimate1 = d.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::*[@class="actestimate"]').get_attribute('innerText')
    estimate2 = d.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::*[@class="actrevest"]').get_attribute('innerText')
    print(title, estimate1, estimate2)
```

By using the xpath to the ticker class, I was able to then xpath out for each record to its corresponding estimates.

Honestly, CSS is a valid method, but I rarely trust it. Xpath has always served me better.